# increasing buffer numbers when streaming with OpenAL

Tags: ios, macos, audio-streaming, openal

I have a fairly simple question involving the generation and deletion of buffers when streaming PCM via OpenAL.  Not doing anything fancy at all other than creating, filling, queueing, polling, and deleting the buffers when they're done playing.  It just saves me from having to do it the hard way via Core Audio.  I'm sure you all understand ...

But after a sufficient amount of time, the thing just craps out and I've just realized that even when I successfully delete a series of buffers after having completed playback, when I allocate new ones for the next bit of audio, the buffer numbers continue to increase.  Is this to be expected?  Will these buffer numbers wrap around when they reach whatever the maximum limit is, or is this a sign that the buffers aren't actually being deleted?  I'm checking error results after alDeleteBuffers() and all seems good, but perhaps there's something I'm missing?

Perhaps a more general question would be if I'd be better off allocating a series of buffers myself and just keeping them around, rather than handing them back to OpenAL immediately after I'm done with them and rely upon it's allocation strategy.  I'm operating upon OSX/iOS here if that pertinent.  Comments/advice from anyone who's had similar experience would be very welcome at this point ...

Comment: To answer my own question (somewhat), experimentation has shown that creating/deleting most anything in OpenAL results in increasing numeric id sequences. I can only assume that the good folks who maintain this thing envisioned the possibility of wrap-around and got it right ...

Comment: As for my problem with OpenAL eventually "crapping out", I've learned that if one wants to guarantee a successful buffer deletion when shutting down a streaming source, even if the source indicates that it isn't currently processing the buffer, then a call to alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, 0) is guaranteed to detach the buffer(s), thus allowing them to be deleted. Having learned this, I shall sleep well tonite ...